# Oracle ROWNUM with multiple joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join, rownum, right-join

I'm trying to execute a query on an Oracle database.

My table structure is:

- d--o one-to-one
- o--r one-to-many
- o--m many-to-many (via mtm)

I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT o.id ID, ROWNUM rn                                               /*row 1*/
FROM TABLE_D d
LEFT JOIN TABLE_O o ON d.O_ID=o.ID 
RIGHT JOIN TABLE_R r ON r.O_ID = o.ID AND r.TYPE = 'SOME_TYPE'          /*row 4*/
RIGHT JOIN TABLE_MTM mtm ON o.ID = mtm.ORD_ID                           /*row 5-6*/
RIGHT JOIN TABLE_M m ON mtm.M_ID = m.ID AND m.TYPE = 'SOMETHING_ELSE'   /*row 5-6*/

WHERE o.ACTIVE=0

ORDER BY o.SOME_COL ASC;
```

(This is just a small part of my full query; yes I do need the ROWNUM, and the 'd' table, and everything)

- If I run this query it returns no results.
- If I remove the ROWNUM from the SELECT, it returns the result
- If I remove row 4, it returns results
- If I remove row 5 and row 6, it returns results.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Update:
  All works well on Oracle 12c. 
  Doesn't work correctly on 10g.

Comment: Have you tried prefixing the table alias "d" to ROWNUM in line 1?

Comment: ROWNUM is not a column of the table.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a lot of things:

```
SELECT o.id ID, ROWNUM as rn                                               /*row 1*/
FROM TABLE_D d LEFT JOIN
     TABLE_O o
     ON d.O_ID = o.ID AND o.ACTIVE = 0 LEFT JOIN
     TABLE_R r
     ON r.O_ID = o.ID AND r.TYPE = 'SOME_TYPE' LEFT JOIN         /*row 4*/
     TABLE_MTM mtm
     ON o.ID = mtm.ORD_ID LEFT JOIN                         /*row 5-6*/
     TABLE_M m
     ON mtm.M_ID = m.ID AND m.TYPE = 'SOMETHING_ELSE'   /*row 5-6*/
ORDER BY o.SOME_COL ASC;
```

First, for a `LEFT JOIN`, the condition on the *second* table should be in the `ON` clause not the `WHERE` clause.  Second, for a `RIGHT JOIN`, the condition on the *first* table should be in the `ON` clause.  A condition on the *second* table (for a `RIGHT JOIN`) does not filter rows.

In any case, you should not mix `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` in the same query, unless you really know what you are doing and you really need it.  I suspect that `LEFT JOIN` and the above construct should be correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really appreciate the best practice advises, but I still don't know why this is happening.

Comment: @JakabfiAttila . . . It is happening presumably because no rows have `o.ACTIVE = 0`, although with the combinations of left and right joins are hard to follow so there might be some other condition as well.